# How would I accomplish this with nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Just wanting to know how I would accomplish something like this as a 1 liner with list comprehension, just simple subtracting list index 1 from 0, for each sublist of the main list.

```
value = [[-20, 20], [-20, 20], [32, 32]]
value[0] = value[0][0] - value[0][1]
value[1] = value[1][0] - value[1][1]
value[2] = value[2][0] - value[2][1]
```

Comment: To figure out how to write something as a list comprehension, you just need to imagine writing it as a loop -- `new_values = []` `for sublist in value: new_value = sublist[0] - sublist[1]` `new_values.append(new_value)`.  Then you drop the append and put the `new_value` first, but leave the for loop order the same: `new_values = [sublist[0]-sublist[1] for sublist in value]`.  It works the same way for nested listcomps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
value = [v[0] - v[1] for v in value]
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks mate, and say i also wanted to abs() the resulting value from the subtraction, could that easily be done in the same comperhension or am i better off just doing

value = [abs(v) for v in value]

as a seprate line

Comment: @user1908180: Just add the `abs()`: `[abs(v[0] - v[1]) for v in value]`. The left-hand expression is evaluated for each loop, you can expand it at will.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_values = [ v[0] - v[1] for v in values ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2

    [(v-i) for v,i in values]
```